# Cannot change title of Kendo Export to Excel button on toolbar

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to change the title of the "Export to Excel" button on Kendo Grid's toolbar, but although I tried to apply many different suggestions, still cannot update. How to change this?

```
<script>
    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                toolbar: ["excel"],
                excel: {
                    text: "Test 1", //did not make any sense
                    title: "Test 2", //did not make any sense
                    fileName: "Export.xlsx",
                    filterable: true
                },
                //code omitted for brevity

    }).data("kendoGrid");
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of just passing a string in the `toolbar: [...]` you can pass an object which with the right property will adjust the text.

change:

```
toolbar: ["excel"];
```

to

```
toolbar: [{name: 'excel', text: 'custom excel export button'}];
```

full example:

```
<script>
    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        toolbar: [{name:'excel',text:'custom excel export button'}],
        excel: {
            fileName: "Export.xlsx",
            filterable: true
        },
    }).data("kendoGrid");
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect!.. Thanks a lot :)